# Put a Variable in List Name

Tags: python, list

Essentially, I want to create and fill a list based on the contents of a variable. The relevant data is being read from a (JSON) text file.

```
#Check if a game was won, and assign a variable to `outcome`
if game['stats']['win'] == True:
                outcome = "victory"
            else:
                outcome = "defeat"

#put the no. objectives taken in that game in a 'wins' or 'losses' list
objectives_in_(outcome).append(game['stats']['objectives_taken'])
```

So outside of a useful for-loop, I would want something a result which looks something like this:

```
print(objectives_in_victory)

7
```

In case my question remains unclear, I am reading a file that will contain data on whether a match was won, and how many objectives were secured. If the game was won, the number of objectives in that game will be assigned to a 'win list' and visa versa for losses.

I tried using a dictionary which was suggested elsewhere on SO for approaching similar tasks, but matches which have the same outcome and no. objectives are not duplicated making averaging impossibe and causing data to be excluded. It took me a long time to realise this..

Comment: For the record, your question has nothing to do with environment variables so shouldn't have that tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a `dict` of lists that looks like this:

```
objectives_in = {"victory": [], "defeat": []}
```

You can use it similar to what you have in your example:

```
objectives_in[outcome].append(game['stats']['objectives_taken'])

# Example stats:
count = len(objectives_in["victory"])
print("Number of victories:", count)
print("Average objectives:", sum(objectives_in["victory"]) / count)
```